# Why I get error SQL command not properly ended while I execute UPDATE query

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to migrate such a simple `MySQL` query to `Oracle SQL` using `PLSQL`

```
UPDATE submaterial SET `Name` = '{$name}'".($image !== null ? ", `Picture` = '{$image}'" : "")." WHERE SubmaterialID = {$id};
```

When I migrate to PLSQL I get something like this

```
UPDATE submaterial SET Name = p_name 
     CASE WHEN p_image != NULL THEN 
       Picture = p_image
     WHERE SubmaterialID = p_Id;
```

When I want to execute this I get error

```
Error(408,6): PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

I try also something like this but also get same error message

```
 UPDATE submaterial SET Name = p_name 
     CASE WHEN  p_image IS NOT NULL THEN
       Picture = p_image
     WHERE SubmaterialID = p_Id;
```

Does anyone know where did I made mistake ?  How to write this king of query to `Oracle SQL` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be

```
UPDATE submaterial
   SET Name = p_name,
       picture = CASE WHEN p_image IS NOT NULL THEN p_image END
 WHERE SubmaterialID = p_Id;
```

i.e. you have to take `picture =` out of `case` expression.